# What pure perf choice for a rest API?

Tags: python, node.js, performance, rest, raspberry-pi3

For a project I need to design an REST api who will receive, execute a basic treatment and response on 100.000 request.

- The requests will be sent on my API one by one with a minimal delay (like each second or less)
- The API will be hosted on a litle Rapsberry 3 and I aim to get the best perf 
  (the minimal time between the send of first request and response to the last one).

My question is :

***What techno would you use for this ? And mostly why this one ?***

For now my choice is node.js because I already work with it. 
In my mind I've this posibilities but no idea of perf :

- Node.js (because V8 and express)
- Python 3
- PHP 5 (seems to have surprising good perfs)
- Scala
- Ruby

**C/C++ not an option**

Any proposition and arguement will be read with attention and interest !
Thx !

Comment: 100.000 requests is nothing... if spread out over a week... :-P

Comment: @deceze "The requests will be sent on my API one by one with a minimal delay." means they'll be sent one by one each second or less :)
But thanks for notice me it wasn't clear :)

Comment: So you have a fixed number of requests and they need to be processed as fast as possible? Usually it's the other way around... you expect an infinite number of requests with a certain frequency...

Comment: Exactly ! It's maybe uncommon but it's my subject

Comment: It *must* be a REST API? You could do wonders with a streaming API and asynchronous processing here...

Comment: It was asked to be a REST API but I can explore Streaming API option !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask, a Python framework will get you started in minutes. It is lightweight (good for RPi3), easy to setup and pretty straightforward for REST APIs.

Example:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/do/something', methods=['POST'])
def api_v1_do_something():
    return json_response(json.dumps({
      "result": "success",
      "data": {"a": 1, "b": 2},
    }))
```

http://flask.pocoo.org

Comment: Thanks for tip, adding a framework on python won't degrade native good perfs ? I'm gonna take a look on Flask anyway :)

Comment: With the proposed setup your server will be able to process (do a "basic treatment" for) 800 requests per second in worst case (on a PRi3). This is approximate and you can actually measure it. Taking into account the fact that "the requests will be sent on my API one by one with a minimal delay" there is no performance problem present.

Comment: Ok ok , thanks ! gonna try it this evenining